# I am getting, TypeError: Node Function not defined but required and module exported? What should I do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, api, backend

I am creating the backend for an app that looks up movies via OpenImdb. This code works standalone without node but when I require jquery, then export as a module and call it via index.js it gives me an error saying that Jquery does not contain a get function. I looked up many places and everyone seems to have this problem when they did not require correctly and I used https://www.npmjs.com/package/jQuery page to make sure I'm doing it right. Does anyone have any suggestions as to where I'm going wrong?

This is the snippet of code from my Model for the IMDB lookup.

```js
let $ = require('jquery');
let methods = {
    apikey: "MyAPIKEY"
};

methods.getMovie = async function (userSearch)
{
    return await $.get("http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=" + userSearch + "&apikey=" + this.apikey);
}
methods.searchByTitle = async function (Title)
{
    let data = await $.get("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" + Title + "&apikey=" + this.apikey);
    console.log(data);
    return data;
}
exports.data = methods;
```

Thanks so much for any help guys!

Matthew R

Comment: Are you using jquery in node?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is not meant to be used in a Node.js environment. For fetching data in Node trying using [Got](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got).

Comment: Thank you, I was unaware that you could not use JQuery to get data like an ajax in node.js